# The source of vibration on a Chladni plate

Tags: waves, acoustics, resonance

By changing the location of the vibration on a circular Chladni plate, I found that the patterns change for the same frequencies at which the plate was vibrated from the centre. What effect does the source point of vibration have on the characteristics of standing waves produced in the Chladni plate?

Comment: More on [Chladni plates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+chladni).

Answer (score 2):

At the position of the vibrating source the amplitude of the oscillation of the palte at that position is fixed by the amplitude of the vibrating source.

So with source in one position there may be a node at another position on the plate.  Moving the source to the position where there that node was before would mean that it was no longer a node and so the pattern generated would be different.

Comment: Is there any equation that takes into account the location of the source point of vibration?

Comment: @Bodvarion There is no simple relationship. You need to have a look at the references that Qmechanic has given to you and the links therein.

Comment: How would this affect the Chaldni's law  which relates the frequency of modes of vibration for flat circular surfaces with fixed center as a function of the numbers m of diametric (linear) nodes and n of radial (circular) nodes. It is stated as the equation


 f=C(m+2n)^p
where C and p are coefficients which depend on the properties of the plate.

Moving the source of oscillation off centre has resulted in different patterns which do not show any circular nodes according to my experimentation